# Excel Amazon Seller Web Scraper Issue

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping

I have been trying to get this code to work for workflow efficiency purposes, but I cannot seem to make it function correctly.

Steps:
1. Login to Amazon Seller

2. Use order numbers in column A and place them in searchbox to search
3. Search for element innerText of "Estimated Delivery:" and scrape information into column B adjacent the order number
4. Move onto the next order number and repeat process until order number column is empty.

The webpage code (what I'm trying to obtain is highlighted):

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
Dim MyBrowser As InternetExplorer

Sub MyAmazonSellereEDD()

    Dim MyHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
    Dim MyURL As String
    Dim oSignInLink As HTMLLinkElement
    Dim oInputEmail As HTMLInputElement
    Dim oInputPassword As HTMLInputElement
    Dim oInputSignInButton As HTMLInputButtonElement

    'InputSearchOrder will be the destination for order numbers taken from the workbook
    Dim InputSearchOrder As HTMLInputElement

    Dim InputSearchButton As HTMLInputButtonElement
    Dim IE As InternetExplorer
    Dim AAOrder As Workbook
    Dim AAws As Worksheet
    Dim AAws2 As Worksheet

    Dim R As Range
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim i As Long
    Dim ar As Variant
    Dim elems As IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim TDelement As HTMLTableCell

    Dim ExcludWords() As Variant, a As Range, b As Long, LR As Long

    ExcludWords = Array("Estimated Delivery:")


    MyURL = "https://sellercentral.amazon.com/gp/homepage.html"

    Set IE = New InternetExplorer

    ' Open the browser and navigate.
    With IE
        .Silent = True
        .navigate MyURL
        .Visible = True
        Do
            DoEvents
        Loop Until .readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    End With


    ' Get the html document.
    Set HTMLDoc = IE.document



    With HTMLDoc
        .all.Item("username").Value = "blankityblank@blank.net"
        .all.Item("password").Value = "*********"
        .all.Item("sign-in-button").Click
    End With

      Do
        DoEvents
    Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:08"))

    'Set AAOrder = Application.Workbooks.Open("Z:\Automation Anywhere\5 Automated Tracking Imports\Amazon Prime\PrimeOrdersWithNoFulfillment.csv")
    'Set AAws = AAOrder.Worksheets("PrimeOrdersWithNoFulfillment")





    x = 2
    'Do Until Range("A" & x) = ""
    If Range("B" & x).Value = "" Then

        'If AAws.Range("B" & x).Value = "" Then
        'x = x + 1
        Do Until Range("A" & x) = ""
            Set InputSearchOrder = HTMLDoc.getElementById("sc-search-field")
            InputSearchOrder.Value = Range("A" & x)

            Set InputSearchButton = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("sc-search-button")(0)
            InputSearchButton.Click
              Do
                DoEvents
            Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))


            Set elems = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("td")


            'ExcludWords = Array("Package Weight:", "Tracking ID:", "Ship Date:", "Carrier:", "Shipping Service:")


            i = 2

            For Each TDelement In elems
                If TDelement.className = "data-display-field" And InStr(TDelement.innerText, "Estimated Delivery:") Then
                    Range("B" & x).Value = TDelement.innerText
                    i = i + 1
                End If
            Next







            LR = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            For i = 1 To LR
            Set a = Cells(i, "B")
            For b = 0 To UBound(ExcludWords)
                a.Formula = Replace((a.Formula), ExcludWords(b), "")
                    Next b
            Next i


        'End If
        x = x + 1
        Loop


     'Loop
     End If

    Err_Clear:
        If Err <> 0 Then
            Err.Clear
            Resume Next
        End If

    MsgBox ("Process is done! :)")


    End Sub
```

My issue is that when it scrapes the data, the words "Estimated Delivery:" and the actual estimated delivery date it is supposed to scrape are separate, but still should be included in the output data in column B. What it's doing is finding and inserting only "Estimated Delivery:" and then using the code, it trims those characters as instructed. The space is still blank after that. I'm not sure what the issue is.

Answer (score 2):

The `TDelement` you pick up in the following part of code only includes "Estimated Delivery:" in its `innerText`, the part with the date is actually a separate `TDelement`:

```
For Each TDelement In elems
    If TDelement.className = "data-display-field" And InStr(TDelement.innerText, "Estimated Delivery:") Then
        Range("B" & x).Value = TDelement.innerText
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next
```

As there is not any unique information in the html code (e.g. id, name etc.)  to use to reference the `TDelement` that contains the date you could use the reference you already have in conjunction with `NextSibling` so that you get the element after the one that contains the text "Estimated Delivery:". Perhaps try this (unable to test anything at the moment but should work):

```
For Each TDelement In elems
    If TDelement.className = "data-display-field" And InStr(TDelement.innerText, "Estimated Delivery:") Then
        Range("B" & x).value = TDelement.NextSibling.innerText
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next
```

Comment: I tried it, and it's throwing the "VBA object does not support this property or method". I realise it specifically can't reference the element, and I've been trying workaround methods such as yours. Would I need to update the reference library for the .NextSibling.innerText to work?

Comment: So I was messing around with the code, and `Range("B" & x).value = TDelement.Children(0).innerText` was the closest I got to obtaining the Delivery Date information, but that presented a whole new set of problems as it added a bunch more data to the cell and the macro threw an object error after the first cell was filled with the extra data.